# Paperclip s3_host_alias not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying use the Cloudfront CNAME in s3_host_alias but isn't working.

#### config/s3_config.yml

```
development:
  url: ":s3_host_alias"
  s3_host_alias: dev-cdn.mysite.com
production:
  url: ":s3_host_alias"
  s3_host_alias: cdn.mysite.com
```

#### models/profile.rb

```
def self.s3_config
    @@s3_config ||= YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/s3_config.yml")).result)[Rails.env]
end

has_attached_file :avatar, :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml", :url => self.s3_config['url'], :s3_host_alias => self.s3_config['s3_host_alias'], :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :circle => "130x130#", :thumb => "50x50>" }, :default_url => "avatar/missing.jpg", :path => ":class/:id/:attachment/:style/:hash.:extension", :url => ":class/:id/:attachment/:style/:hash.:extension", :hash_secret => "***"
```

Tried  the code with CNAME direct in model and don't work too.

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml", :url => ":s3_host_alias", :s3_host_alias => "dev-cdn.mysite.com", :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :circle => "130x130#", :thumb => "50x50>" }, :default_url => "avatar/missing.jpg", :path => ":class/:id/:attachment/:style/:hash.:extension", :url => ":class/:id/:attachment/:style/:hash.:extension", :hash_secret => "***"
```

The website keeps using the full s3 bucket url...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well: neither the :s3_host_alias nor :url would read from config/s3.yml. I was able to make it work by putting both fields in the model but keeping s3.yml for the bucket, access_key_id, and secret.

A quick workaround might look something like this:

```
if Rails.env.production?
    host_alias = "cdn.mysite.com"
elsif Rails.env.development?
    host_alias = "dev-cdn.mysite.com"
end
```

then

```
has_attached_file   :avatar, 
                    ...
                    :url            => ":s3_alias_url",
                    :s3_host_alias  => host_alias,
                    :credentials => ...
```

Comment: It also looks like you may be setting :url twice?

Comment: It is not working, while generating expiring_url    "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/xxxxxxxx"
only working for url "https://bucket/xxxxxxxxxxxx"